# If air was significantly compressed, and then the force compressing it suddenly disappeared (no container), what would happen?

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure, ideal-gas, explosions

Question:
If air was significantly compressed, and then the force compressing it suddenly disappeared (no container), what would happen?

Side Question:
I'm imagining significantly compressed, but what kind of pressure would be necessary for that?

Thoughts:
It has been a while since I took chemistry and physics, but what I think is that it would rapidly expand and exert similar pressure to whatever the container was exerting on it in all directions? So similar to what an explosion from heating gas or what not would do?

Comment: This kind of situation is commonplace: Think of popping a balloon. Pieces of whatever material formerly composed the container are ejected as the gas expands to fill some larger volume, then the wave energy is carried outward further on a traveling pressure wave.

Comment: And the expansion of this gas will approximate an [adiabatic expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Ideal_gas_.28reversible_process.29) and therefore the air will drop in temperature.

Comment: @fibonatic Doesn't it depend on the sign of the Joule-Thompson coefficient whether temperature drops or rises?  I think it can be positive or negative for air depending upon the T & P.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1084398/

Comment: @DavePhD I am not sure if the Joule-Thompson effect is applicable in this situation. The cooling I am talking about ocurres due to the work done by the expanding gas.

Comment: @fibonatic but expanding into a vacuum does no work

Comment: @DavePhD but the surrounding is not vaccuum.

Comment: @fibonatic, if it's not against a vacuum, the drop or rise in the temperature would be a combination of the Joule-Thompson effect and the effect of expanding against whatever external pressure there is.